# convert string to date gets ( String was not recognized as a valid DateTime)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to convert a string to a DateTime type in c# 
when i get the current time string and convert it,

it works but it wont work on my string, although they are the same time format 
i have tried this  what am i doing wrong?

```
 DateTime ReqRealDate = new DateTime();
            DateTime NowDateFormat = new DateTime();
            UPR.ReqID = Request.QueryString["reqID"];
            string DateOfRequest = Request["Date"];
            userInfo.UserID = Convert.ToInt32(Request["userID"]);
            Session["TempUser"] = userInfo;
            string dateFormat = "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";
            string NowDate = DateTime.Now.ToString(dateFormat);
            NowDateFormat = DateTime.ParseExact(NowDate, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            ReqRealDate = DateTime.ParseExact(DateOfRequest, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

> DateOfRequest = "6/3/2018 3:53:56 PM"
>       NowDate = "6/3/2018 03:58:58 PM"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have look at time  `3:53:56` which is not exactly as `hh:mm:ss`.

You should consider adding more reliable format or may be a list:

```
  string[] dateFormat = new string[] {
                   "MM/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",
                   "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",
                   "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",
                   "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",
                   "MM/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
                   "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
                   "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
                   "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"};
            NowDateFormat = DateTime.ParseExact(NowDate, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Or make your date string to match a specific format, that a single string dateFormat can be enough.

Comment: such noob mistake from me , maybe because i was working for the last 12 hours , thank you

Comment: No, this happens to all of us. especially to programmers and vampires, that are up only at nights